Strange pipeline behavior with variable group
When I set the agent variable name in variables.yml the pipeline works as expected.
app.yml
# Rest of the code
stages:
    - stage: DEVApprove
      displayName: 'DEV'
      jobs:
        - template: /templates/manual_validation.yml@CICD

    - stage: DEV
      displayName: 'Development'
      variables:
        - group: DEV
        - name: environment
          value: ${{ variables.env }}
      pool:
        name: ${{ variables.agent_pool }}

variables.yml
variables:
  - name: env
    value: 'DEV'
  - name: agent_pool
    value: 'DEVAGENT-G2'
Changed to this:

- stage: DEV
  displayName: 'Development'
  variables:
    - group: DEV
    - name: environment
      value: ${{ variables.env }}
  pool:
    name: $(agent_pool)

Where agent_pool is taken from variable group: enter image description here
It leads to the error:
##[error]Pipeline does not have permissions to use the referenced pool(s) . For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.
I don't understand it, because I changed only the way how the agent_pool name is passing.
